# Why lightweight nodes are less secure?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, full-node

as you know there is two main type of wallets:

full node and

light node

I've read in some advice that just using full node for more security stuff
and the next question is what is the type of blockchain.com wallet?
many thnx :kiss:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Why lightweight nodes are less secure?**

A lightweight node is less secure because it doesn't store its own copy of the entire blockchain.

This means it cannot verify for itself the integrity of incoming blocks with complete certainty. It generally has to rely on the integrity of an external server for at least some starting block. This is the kind of trust of third parties that Satoshi Nakamoto was trying to avoid when creating Bitcoin.

> **and the next question is**

One question per question. Please use the "Ask Question" button at top right to ask a new question. You can include a link back to this question if it helps clarify your next question.